# How to update workflow status column?

Tags: workflow, 2016

I have an approval workflow that has the status "Failed On Start (retrying)" but it it appears to be running and is creating tasks for the approvers.

How do I update the status to say "In progress"? Can this be done in powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping the workflow for the specific item with "Failed on start (retrying)" and re-run it?

To end workflow:

1. Select item and open menu (by clicking on the 3-dot icon)
2. Select Workflow
3. From the running workflow, click the one with the 'failed...' *- you should see at least some details of any error*
4. Click "End this workflow" *- this should turn the status to cancelled*
5. Re-run the workflow (either manually or depending on your trigger event)

Comment: The workflow is still running and is sending out the tasks. I do not want to end the workflow as it will just annoy the users having to approve the tasks again.